# Invalid syntax during reading of csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to read a file using csv.reader in python. I am new to Python and am using `Python 2.7.15`.

The example that I am trying to recreate is gotten from "**Reading CSV Files With csv**" section of [this](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) page. This is the code:

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

During execution of the code, I am getting the following errors:

```
File "ross_test2.py", line 11
  print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this error. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `f` in front of strings (f-strings) are only for versions above python 3.5, so try this:

```
print('Column names are',", ".join(row))
```

Or:

```
print('Column names are %s'%", ".join(row))
```

Or:

```
print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
```

Comment: U9-Forward: Thanks for your help. I presume, I should also change the other print statements, perhaps.

Comment: @Ross Happy to help, :-), , please accept if it works :-), and upvote :-)

Comment: U9-Forward: I really appreciate your help :-) I have accepted this answer (it will take 4 mins to show up, I guess.) I am wondering how I should change this print statement (I am getting errors in that now): " print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.') "

Comment: @Ross Try this `print('\t%s works in the %s department, and was born in %s.'%row[:3])`

Comment: @Ross From data i saw there, this will work too: `print('\t%s works in the %s department, and was born in %s.'%row)`

Comment: U9-Forward: Thanks for your help (again.) I followed your suggestion. I am getting this error: "print('\t%s works in the %s department, and was born in %s.'%row)" Actually, the thing that I want to learn is how to get the characters given the row and column position in this file (using standard python libraries.)